# Transcribing System-Audio (output) to Text through Python

Tags: python, audio, pyaudio, transcription

I am currently working on a project where i need to get the output of my current audio device (Headset Earphone or others) and transcribe them to text through a language model. The whole think needs to work offline (thats why i use vosk)

Librarys i use atm:

- vosk (lib for the ai model)
- pyaudiowpatch (pyaudio itself does not support loopback audio input)

The Model itself works as I have tried it with my own microphone but the moment i try to use the system audio the model only returns random words and letters that dont make sense in the slightest.

I tried to change to a different audio device or directly to a windows mixer/sampler etc. without any results.

I use following code:

```
from vosk import Model, KaldiRecognizer
import pyaudiowpatch

# The ai models are downloaded from "https://alphacephei.com/vosk/models"
# German model: https://alphacephei.com/vosk/models/vosk-model-de-0.21.zip
# English model: https://alphacephei.com/vosk/models/vosk-model-en-us-0.22.zip

model = Model(r"C:\Users\Q620763\Desktop\stt\lan_models\vosk-model-de-0.21")
#model_1 = Model(r"C:\ Users\Q620763\Desktop\stt\lan_models\vosk-model-en-us-0.22")

recognizer = KaldiRecognizer(model, 48000)

#mic = pyaudio.PyAudio()
audio = pyaudiowpatch.PyAudio()
    
wasapi_info = audio.get_host_api_info_by_type(pyaudiowpatch.paWASAPI)
default_speakers = audio.get_device_info_by_index(wasapi_info["defaultOutputDevice"])
print(default_speakers)

RATE = 48000
#mic_stream = mic.open(format=pyaudio.paInt16, channels=1, rate =16000, input=True, frames_per_buffer=8192)
#mic_stream.start_stream()

audio_stream = audio.open(format=pyaudiowpatch.paInt32,
                          channels=default_speakers['maxOutputChannels'],
                          rate=RATE,
                          input=True,
                          input_device_index=17,
                          frames_per_buffer= 8192)

audio_stream.start_stream()

print("Start tracking")
while True:

    data = audio_stream.read(4096, exception_on_overflow = False)
    if recognizer.AcceptWaveform(data):
        text = recognizer.Result()
        
        print(text[14:-3])
```

It currently uses the German model. If you want to try and run the code model_1 would be english:

```
model_1 = Model(r"{YOUR PATH}\vosk-model-en-us-0.22")
```